# How hide UILabel after 2 seconds Swift?

Tags: swift, uikit, uilabel

When I taped button UILabel appears and immediately disappears again. I need it to disappear after a few seconds. It's my first app and I can't solve this problem.
Thanks!

```
func done() {
    if sauserImageView.isHidden == false && cupImageView.isHidden == false && spoonImageView.isHidden == false {
        winningLabel.isHidden = false

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Please include some code so that we know what you have tried so far. Please read how to make a [Minimal,Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added some code,  but I already have a solution. Thanx

Answer (score 8):

You can perform a delayed action by using the DispatchQueue API, e.g.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    self.label.isHidden = true
}
```

Or if you want to animate the hiding, use UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:) or UIView.animate(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:) e.g.:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
    self.label.alpha = 0
}
```

Good luck!